# How can DNS propagation work without editing domain name to do it

Tags: dns, nameservers

I have a reseller account for the chilean domain name locatarios.cl the domain is still into this reseller account server IP 190.215.113.207 the domain is pointed to this server IP using my old DNS nameservers

Now the strange thing and the reason of my question

I purchased 5 days ago a VPS with another company, a new IP I got and obviously a new server. The provider created in Cpanel WHM 2 nameservers

ns1.locatarios.cl
ns2.locatarios.cl

I never edited my domain name locatarios.cl to poing to this server, neither to this IP because first I must move my files and then change the DNS or IP

The strange thing is:

the ns1 and ns2 created by the provider really point to the new IP 200.35.156.63

the domain point to 190.215.113.207 (old server)
the dns not created by me point to 200.35.156.63 (new server)

How can that be possible? I never created those nameservers

THE SERVER PROVIDER DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO MY DOMAIN NAME

Any ideas ?

Comment: you should ask this kind of questions on your VPS provider

Comment: Yes I did but i got no good explanation, there are some good people here with dns nameservers knowledge